# Apache ReverseProxy different paths

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I would like to proxy specific URL paths to different internal ports:

```
example.com/transmission -> localhost:9091
example.com -> standard apache file server
```

I have the following in my apache conf file:

```
ProxyPass /transmission/ http://localhost:9091/
ProxyPassReverse /transmission/ http://localhost:9091/
```

The problem is that if I access example.com/transmission, it hits localhost:9091 fine, and then gets forwarded to example.com/transmission/web which produces a 'file not found' error.

For some reason, the exact path /transmission is working, but /transmission/*anythingelse* is not.  I have played around with various combinations of adding/removing slashes, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after the changes to the config?  The symptoms you're seeing do not match with the configuration that you've provided.

Comment: Yes, apache was restarted after each change

Comment: So, `/transmission` proxies?  Because with the config you're provided, it shouldn't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ProxyPassMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) directive instead.

Comment: Works a charm!!